# Freeze HTMl but keep JavaScript running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make when timediff is <=0 html freezes at 00:00 but javascript keeps countdown to minus so it can be removed when timdiff <= -90000 ?

```
<script>
    var timer1;
    function cdtd1() {
        var sad1 = new Date();
        var dolazak1 = new Date(sad1.getFullYear(),sad1.getMonth(),sad1.getDate(),13,37,00);
        var timeDiff1 = dolazak1.getTime() - sad1.getTime();
        if (timeDiff1 <= -90000) {

            $("#Box1").remove();
        }

            var sekunde1 = Math.floor(timeDiff1 / 1000);
            var minute1 = Math.floor(sekunde1 / 60);
            var sati1 = Math.floor(minute1 / 60);
            var dani1 = Math.floor(sati1 / 24);
            sati1 %= 24;
            minute1 %= 60;
            sekunde1 %= 60;

            $("#dani1Box").html(dani1);
            $("#sati1Box").html(sati1 + ':');
            $("#Ispis1").html('SOME TEXT '+ minute1 + ':' + sekunde1);
            $("#sekunde1Box").html(sekunde1);
            $("#timeDiff1").html(timeDiff1);


            timer1 = setTimeout(cdtd1, 1000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
             cdtd1();
        });
        </script>
```

Here is the html, it's all in one box with spacing

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="Box1">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="Ispis1"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*html freezes*"?

Comment: By itself html is always "freezed".. with "freeze" he means "html should be static.. no changes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
if(timeDiff1 <= 0){
        $("#Ispis1").html('SOME TEXT 0:0');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with how jQuery works, but I'm guessing the following is where you change the HTML

```
$("#dani1Box").html(dani1);
$("#sati1Box").html(sati1 + ':');
$("#Ispis1").html('SOME TEXT '+ minute1 + ':' + sekunde1);
$("#sekunde1Box").html(sekunde1);
$("#timeDiff1").html(timeDiff1);
```

Assuming that's the case, then just make it

```
if(timeDiff1 >= 0){
    $("#dani1Box").html(dani1);
    $("#sati1Box").html(sati1 + ':');
    $("#Ispis1").html('SOME TEXT '+ minute1 + ':' + sekunde1);
    $("#sekunde1Box").html(sekunde1);
    $("#timeDiff1").html(timeDiff1);
}
```

Then those will be skipped as soon as the timer is below zero.

Comment: I would assume by the code you posted that you know how an if statement works. That's all it is.

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question, after timediff <= 0 html must become static, and this won't make it static

Comment: @user3366851 I understood it perfectly. I would assume your clock would be what you want at 0, which is why it will change up to 0, and then once below, it does nothing.